# Visual Studio Goto Line# or Goto Region?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

For example:

```
Line 12: #region VoidA
Line 13: void foo() {}
Line 14: #end region

...

Line 200: void test() {
Line 201:   foo(); //Comment: Refer to #VoidA(click to navigate)
Line 202: }
```

Is it any comment or notation i can place on test() can let me click and make VS2010 scroll to the Line of foo() or region VoidA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [HyperAddin extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/49B1C42B-424B-44CE-9BB1-22B4EC91E577) might do what you are looking for if you don't mind using whatever syntax it wants to see.